# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a Xcode project generated by Unity3D. Out of nowhere came this error. I just deleted some old Software Images of old iOS versions. But I think that couldn't cause this error. Does anybody has an idea to solve this issue?

library not found for -liPhone-lib

http://f.cl.ly/items/1z060d3P3h3x0Y3M2s0K/Bildschirmfoto%202012-01-07%20um%2015.28.37.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out! The solution is to install Unity3D again. I don't know how or why, but Xcode needs some resources provided by Unity3D although the project is already a Xcode project. In opinion this behaviour of Unity3D is very strange. I think it would make more sense if an Xcode project works on its own.But at least we have a solution now.